# SetWindowsHookEx for mouse in 64 bit DLL affects 32 bit apps window movement

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, dll-injection, setwindowshookex

I have 32 bit program which spawns supplied apps with `CreateProcess` and attaches 32 bit DLL to capture mouse events. And it works just fine. DLL sends data to the main program with `SendMessage`.

This program can also spawn 64 bit apps and it has to attach 64 bit DLL to them. So I just did a copy from 32 bit project and changed bitness. Then I cleaned 64 bit EXE (because the logic already in 32 bit EXE).

After all that steps I have:

1. 32 bit EXE file to spawn apps and control window movement
2. 32 DLL which attaches to all 32 bit apps, captures mouse messages and sends to x32 EXE
3. 64 bit empty EXE to attach 64 bit DLL to 64 bit apps
4. 64 bit DLL to capture mouse messages and send data to 32 bit EXE

The problem is that when I set the hook in 64 bit DLL:

```
::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, MouseProc, ModuleFromAddress(MouseProc), dwThreadId);
```

The window movement becomes very choppy. The `MouseProc` is as simple as that:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return ::CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And still it creates movement problems even for 32 bit apps. The same procedure in 32 bit DLL looks like:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (hookWindow) {
        if (wParam == WM_NCLBUTTONUP || wParam == WM_LBUTTONUP) {
            // send data to main EXE the click was done
        }
        else if (wParam != WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN && wParam != WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            if (moving) {
                return true; // another routine does movement
            }
        }
    }

    return ::CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);   
}
```

Why does 64 bit DLL with empty hook procedure affects 32 bit apps which actually are managed by 32 bit DLL? If I don't run 64 bit EXE. All works fine.

Comment: I don't think you need separate 32 and 64 bit DLLs for `WH_MOUSE` - "This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. "

Comment: @JonathanPotter - this is for `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook. the `WH_MOUSE` is called in context of thread which got message

Comment: think problem not in your `MouseProc` if it only call `CallNextHookEx` but in something else in your code. hook itself, if correct implemented, not create such problems

Comment: I agree with RbMm that this particular hook doesn't run in the owning thread, but in the per-window thread.  But I agree with Jonathan that a ton of pain would be saved by using `WH_MOUSE_LL`.  If you need to send the data across to the EXE anyway, let Windows take care of that.  (Now, if "attaches to all 32 bit apps" doesn't mean "all" but "only the ones spawned by the controller", then my advice would change)

Comment: @RbMm [That's not what MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Why not use [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) instead? Then you don't have to deal with DLLs at all. The only downside is Raw Input can't block input like a hook can, but you can [combine the two if you need that](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective).

Comment: @JonathanPotter - but are you try set yourself `WH_MOUSE` for thread from another process ? when i try do this i got error `ERROR_HOOK_NEEDS_HMOD` - *Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle.* . think mistake in msdn

Comment: That reads like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What problem are you ultimately trying to solve? What is the reason for those processes to require communication? What higher-level information do you need to pass across process boundaries?

Comment: I need to arrange simultaneous movement of two or more linked windows. The problem is that in 32 DLL I stop mouse events to control window position by EXE, But 64 DLL doesn't know since it is not hooked to 32 bit app and continue sending mouse events to the system and chopping is the result of system sets new position and then EXE sets a bit different position. How to get 64 DLL stopped mouse events while window is moving?